# Broken pipe when connecting to Azure Datamarket using http-client-tls

Tags: haskell, https, bing-translator-api

## This is now a [fixed bug](https://github.com/vincenthz/hs-tls/issues/87) in `hs-tls`.

Before I can hit the bing translation api, I have to [obtain an access token](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx). This basically amounts to the following snippet which works fine from `curl`

```
curl -Lp --data-urlencode client_id=$APPID \
         --data-urlencode client_secret=$SECRET \
         --data-urlencode scope='http://api.microsofttranslator.com' \
         --data-urlencode grant_type="client_credentials" \
         https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13
```

and responds immediately with some JSON containing the token. Bear in mind that even bad/malformed requests elicit some response containing an error message although also typically a 400 Bad Request HTTP response code.

### When I try to replicate this in Haskell it fails right away (reformatted):

```
*** Exception: FailedConnectionException2 "datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net"
    443 True <socket: 11>: hPutBuf: resource vanished (Broken pipe)
```

Further, when I try a simpler (https) request to a different host everything works as expected.

## This question is solved when someone can tell me what is going on here.

If you get it working with another library that's useful too, but not really what this question is about.

A self contained example is shown below.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Test where

import Control.Monad
import Data.Maybe
import Network.HTTP.Client as N
import Network.HTTP.Client.TLS as N
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import Debug.Trace


badURL :: String
badURL = "https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13"

goodURL :: String
goodURL = "https://httpbin.org/post"

requestData :: [(BS.ByteString, BS.ByteString)]
requestData = [
  ("client_id", "APPID"),
  ("client_secret", "SECRETSECRET"),
  ("scope", "http://api.microsofttranslator.com"),
  ("grant_type", "client_credentials")]

mkReq :: String -> Request
mkReq url = urlEncodedBody requestData . fromJust $ parseUrl url

go :: String -> IO ()
go url = do
  let addHeaders h r = r { requestHeaders = h ++ requestHeaders r }
      headers = [("User-Agent", "curl/7.39.0")
                ,("Accept", "*/*")
                ]
      req = addHeaders headers (mkReq url)
  N.withManager N.tlsManagerSettings $ \man -> do
    resp <- httpLbs req man
    guard (trace "wefwef" True)
    B.putStrLn $ responseBody resp
    return ()

{-
 - *Main> go goodURL 
 - wefwef
 - {
 -   "args": {}, 
 -   "data": "", 
 -   "files": {}, 
 -   "form": {
 -     "client_id": "APPID", 
 -     "client_secret": "SECRETSECRET", 
 -     "grant_type": "client_credentials", 
 -     "scope": "http://api.microsofttranslator.com"
 -   }, 
 -   "headers": {
 -     "Accept": "*/*", 
 -     "Accept-Encoding": "gzip", 
 -     "Connect-Time": "1", 
 -     "Connection": "close", 
 -     "Content-Length": "119", 
 -     "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
 -     "Host": "httpbin.org", 
 -     "Total-Route-Time": "0", 
 -     "User-Agent": "curl/7.39.0", 
 -     "Via": "1.1 vegur", 
 -     "X-Request-Id": "3ed2de84-a1a3-4560-b7e3-f2dabfe45727"
 -   }, 
 -   "json": null, 
 -   "origin": "108.85.134.2", 
 -   "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
 - }
 - *Main> go badURL 
 - *** Exception: FailedConnectionException2 "datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net" 443 True <socket: 11>: hPutBuf: resource vanished (Broken pipe)
 -}
```

## EDIT:

I've tried `tls-simpleclient` and `tls-retrievecertificate` as well but also got broken pipe errors.

```
$ tls-simpleclient -d -v datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net                                          
sending query:
GET / HTTP/1.0



debug: >> Handshake [ClientHello TLS12 (ClientRandom "\235=wnV\156z\143M\168+n\165`\193\217\132G\144\204\187\178\SOHG\156\EM\195\168\251l\232+") (Session Nothing) [107,103,57,51,56,50,47,53,4,5,10] [0] [(0,"\NUL'\NUL\NUL$datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net"),(65281,"\NUL")] Nothing]
debug: >> Alert [(AlertLevel_Fatal,InternalError)]
tls-simpleclient: send: resource vanished (Broken pipe)

$ .cabal-sandbox/bin/tls-retrievecertificate datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net 443                                     
connecting to datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net on port 443 ...
tls-retrievecertificate: send: resource vanished (Broken pipe)
```

Comment: A good place to start is the debugging instructions for TLS: https://github.com/vincenthz/hs-tls/blob/master/README.md#common-issues

Comment: Well, using `tls-simpleclient` is a lot easier than modifying the `connection` package!

Comment: user5402 - Yes but huge points for effort! Thanks!

Comment: I did learn a lot :-)

Comment: It looks likes several of Microsoft's websites are causing this problem with `hs-tls` and there's already a bug open here: https://github.com/vincenthz/hs-tls/issues/87. I'm going to mark this as solved since all I wanted was to know what was going on and whether or not it was my fault somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net doesn't like Haskell's TLS implementation.

You can add logging of the TLS packets by doing this:

In the `connection` package, make the following changes to  `Network/Connection.hs`

Add `import Network.TLS ((Logging(..))`

Modify `tlsEstablish` as follows:

```
  tlsEstablish :: Handle -> TLS.ClientParams -> IO TLS.Context
  tlsEstablish handle tlsParams = do
      rng <- RNG.makeSystem
      ctx <- TLS.contextNew handle tlsParams rng
 +    let logging = def { loggingPacketSent = (\s -> putStrLn $ "<-- sent packet " ++ s)
 +                      , loggingPacketRecv = (\s -> putStrLn $ "--> recv packet " ++ s)
 +                      }
 +    TLS.contextHookSetLogging ctx logging
      TLS.handshake ctx
      return ctx
```

When you execute `go goodURL` you see the following traffic:

```
<-- sent packet Handshake [ClientHello TLS12 ...
--> recv packet Handshake [ServerHello TLS12 ...
...
```

But when you execute `go badURL` you just see:

```
<-- sent packet Handshake [ClientHello TLS12
<-- sent packet Alert [(AlertLevel_Fatal,InternalError)]
*** Exception: FailedConnectionException2 "datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net" 443 True <socket: 13>: hPutBuf: resource vanished (Broken pipe)
```

The interpretation is:

1. client sends Handshake packet
2. remote side closes connections
3. Broken pipe exception raised on client
4. client sends Alert packet to notify remote side of an internal error (i.e. the broken pipe exception)
5. client raises FailedConnectionException2

Update: You can accomplish the same thing by running:

```
tls-simpleclient -d -v datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net
```

where tls-simpleclient can be found in https://github.com/vincenthz/hs-tls

Comment: Yes I think this is what simpleclient is showing us in the (edited) post.

Comment: So the conclusion is... potentially a bug in http-client-tls or a bug on their end which I can't do anything about. Not that I know enough about tls to debug the library either :/   Time to wikipedia.